# Avoid Out of memory error for big images Android minimum api level should be Froyo(8)

Tags: android, performance, out-of-memory, httpurlconnection, backwards-compatibility

My requirement is to download heavy images size more than 10mb in android but minimum api  level should be 8.
 Previously I used Volley Image Request to download the image but application throws out of memory error.
 I tried with Picasso but still get out of memory error.
 Then i implemented that functionality using HttpsURLConnection

```
 InputStream inputStream = null;
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
    HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection = null;
    try {
        try {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
                SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
                ctx.init(new KeyManager[0], new TrustManager[]{new CustomTrustManager()}, new SecureRandom());
                SSLContext.setDefault(ctx);

                httpsURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) imageUrl.openConnection();
                httpsURLConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(ctx.getSocketFactory());
                httpsURLConnection.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int BUFFER_SIZE = 16 * 1024; // Defining a standard value 8K as Buffer (8192)

        /*
         * Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
         */
        if (httpsURLConnection == null) {
            inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(imageUrl.openConnection().getInputStream(), BUFFER_SIZE);
        } else {
            inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(httpsURLConnection.getInputStream(), BUFFER_SIZE);
        }

        File parentDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED) ? mContext.getExternalFilesDir(null) : mContext.getFilesDir();
        File imageDir = new File(parentDirectory, "Images");
        if (!imageDir.exists()) imageDir.mkdir();
```

with this code i able to download big size images without any error.
Can anybody suggest is this good way to download images? 
Can any other way to do that?

Comment: What is the use of downloading that much big size image?

Comment: What's wrong with httpsUrlConnection for much big sized images? https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html Its good to check for certificate to make sure connected to correct server and users connection wasn't hijacked. This can be done along with httpsUrlConnection so its security should be just fine according to Google!

Comment: Do you want to download this big size images, or just want to display in your app??

Comment: @NigamPatro It is not just issue with very large size but normal images which were not compress by server up they are up  to 2mb also sometimes through error in low api level 8 to 14 or device having low configuration.

Comment: @CmosBattery Thanks for the suggestion. My only concern is that I have not make use of network library like volley for download bcoz for that I am getting out of memory error.is there performance issue with httpsUrlConnection ?